# Modify DB row after query PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to modify my DB after a query. My goal is this: query the values, echo them with a little modify form that, if I hit "modify", the values will be modified in the DB. I don't know if I'm being clear enough, so here's my code, maybe it'll help me explain.

```
<h3>¿Quieres editar tu receta?</h3>
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <h3>Introduce tu email: </h3><input type="text" name="email" placeholder="email"/><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="editar" value="Buscar mi receta" class="send-btn">
</form>
<?php
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Madrid');
    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "db_csw");
    if(!$link){
        die("Conexion fallida: ". mysqli_error());
    }
    if(isset($_POST['editar'])){
        $email = $_POST["email"];
        $query = "SELECT * FROM datosformulario WHERE email LIKE '%".$email."%'";
        $res = mysqli_query($link, $query);
        if($res !== false && mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0){
            while ($aux = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
                $accion = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
                $id = $aux['id'];
                echo "Nombre de la receta: ".$aux['nombrereceta']."<br>";
                echo "Pasos de la receta: ".$aux['pasosreceta']."<br>";
                echo "<br><br>";
                echo "¿Quieres editar esta receta?<br/>";
                echo "<form method='POST' action='".$accion."'>";
                echo "<input type='text' name='nombreRecetaEditada' placeholder='Nombre de la receta'/><br/>";
                echo "<textarea cols='42' rows='10' name='pasosRecetaEditada' placeholder='Pasos de la receta'></textarea><br/>";
                echo "<input type='submit' name='editarReceta' value='Editar' class='send-btn'><br/>";
                echo "</form>";
                if(isset($_POST["editarReceta"])){
                    $nombreRecetaEditada = $_POST["nombreRecetaEditada"];
                    $pasosRecetaEditada = $_POST["pasosRecetaEditada"];
                    $actualizaReceta = "UPDATE datosformulario SET nombrereceta='$nombreRecetaEditada',pasosreceta='$pasosRecetaEditada' WHERE id=$id";
                    $exito = mysqli_query($link, $actualizaReceta);
                    if($exito !== false){
                        echo "Receta modificada";
                    } else {
                        echo "No se pudo modificar la receta";
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            echo "El email introducido no se ha usado para enviar ninguna receta. Por favor, prueba de nuevo";
        }
    }
    mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The problem** is, the control will never reach to this `if(isset($_POST["editarReceta"])){ ...` block even though you've click on the *submit* button the update the values in the table. And that's because it has to cross this `if(isset($_POST['editar'])){ ...` block to reach the former mentioned `if` block.

**The solution** is, take this entire `if(isset($_POST["editarReceta"])){ ... }` outside of the `if(isset($_POST['editar'])){ ... }` block, like this:

```
// your code
if(isset($_POST["editarReceta"])){
    ...
}
if(isset($_POST['editar'])){
    ...
}
// your code
```

Also, to get the `$id` value in the `UPDATE` query, you have to change the form's `action` attribute in the following way,

```
echo "<form method='POST' action='".$accion."?id='".$id.">";
```

So that you could catch the appropriate `$id` in the following way,

```
$id = (int)$_GET['id'];
```

Here's **the complete code**,

```
<h3>¿Quieres editar tu receta?</h3>
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <h3>Introduce tu email: </h3><input type="text" name="email" placeholder="email"/><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="editar" value="Buscar mi receta" class="send-btn">
</form>
<?php
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Madrid');
    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "db_csw");
    if(!$link){
        die("Conexion fallida: ". mysqli_error());
    }

    if(isset($_POST["editarReceta"])){
        $id = (int)$_GET['id'];
        $nombreRecetaEditada = $_POST["nombreRecetaEditada"];
        $pasosRecetaEditada = $_POST["pasosRecetaEditada"];
        $actualizaReceta = "UPDATE datosformulario SET nombrereceta='$nombreRecetaEditada',pasosreceta='$pasosRecetaEditada' WHERE id=$id";
        $exito = mysqli_query($link, $actualizaReceta);
        if($exito !== false){
            echo "Receta modificada";
        } else {
            echo "No se pudo modificar la receta";
        }
    }

    if(isset($_POST['editar'])){
        $email = $_POST["email"];
        $query = "SELECT * FROM datosformulario WHERE email LIKE '%".$email."%'";
        $res = mysqli_query($link, $query);
        if($res !== false && mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0){
            while ($aux = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
                $accion = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
                $id = $aux['id'];
                echo "Nombre de la receta: ".$aux['nombrereceta']."<br>";
                echo "Pasos de la receta: ".$aux['pasosreceta']."<br>";
                echo "<br><br>";
                echo "¿Quieres editar esta receta?<br/>";
                echo "<form method='POST' action='".$accion."?id='".$id.">";
                echo "<input type='text' name='nombreRecetaEditada' placeholder='Nombre de la receta'/><br/>";
                echo "<textarea cols='42' rows='10' name='pasosRecetaEditada' placeholder='Pasos de la receta'></textarea><br/>";
                echo "<input type='submit' name='editarReceta' value='Editar' class='send-btn'><br/>";
                echo "</form>";
            }
        } else {
            echo "El email introducido no se ha usado para enviar ninguna receta. Por favor, prueba de nuevo";
        }
    }
    mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

---

**Sidenote:** Learn about [**prepared statement**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) because right now your queries are susceptible to SQL injection. Also see [**how you can prevent SQL injection in PHP**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: Thank you very much!! You explained that really good, I got it very clear. Also, I'll take a look to those links you gave me, they'll be really helpful.